# How to make bar shape like bell curve in angular-chart?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, chart.js

I am using angular-chart to draw charts in my web application. I Want to make UI for the Bars in the chart as shown in image. I have tried a lot to achieve this UI but not able to make it. Also I searched other librearies for the same UI. We can draw a single bell curve on the graph but I want to make each bar look like a bell curve. 
[image]
Here is the JsFiddle for angular-chart.

Here is the code I am trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/quekid/untd28yq/

```
$scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'   }];
$scope.options = {
scales: {
  yAxes: [
    {
      id: 'y-axis-1',
      type: 'linear',
      display: true,
      position: 'left',
      ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true,
            suggestedMin: 0
        }
    },
    {
      id: 'y-axis-2',
      type: 'linear',
      display: false,
      position: 'right'
    }
   ]
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
 $scope.colors= [{ 
                                fill: true,
                 backgroundColor: "#cb2431"
              }];
```

This will be fill the area under the graph its work for me. Just try it out

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/untd28yq/3/)

Comment: Actually I am looking for the exact UI as shown in the image. Thanks, This will help me to think in a different way

Comment: I don't think you get that exact grap. you just make it in customized way.